# Does calling session_start multiple times create duplicate cookies?

Tags: php, firebug, session-cookies

According to **[this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38104)**, calling session_start and session_write_close multiple times creates duplicate cookies, which, if called many times in a big loop, has the potential to hurt browser performance.

But when I tested this bug, with the following code, Firebug only showed one copy of each cookie under the "Cookies" tab.

```
<?php

session_name('uniqueName1');
session_start();
$_SESSION['Foo1'] = 'Bar1';
session_write_close();

session_name('uniqueName2');
session_start();
$_SESSION['Foo2'] = 'Bar2';
session_write_close();

session_name('uniqueName1');
session_start();
$sessionValue1 = $_SESSION['Foo1'];
session_write_close();

session_name('uniqueName2');
session_start();
$sessionValue2 = $_SESSION['Foo2'];
session_write_close();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p><?php echo $sessionValue1; echo $sessionValue2; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I looking for the multiple cookies the wrong way or is this bug fixed?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

4.3.3 As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.

nothing at all will happen

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

This bug is flagged as `Not a bug` so nor this problem was triggered by a specific system/modif. version or it never exists, by the way the bug is from late `2006` ;)

---

no it won't if you calling `session_start` multiple times one after one. you can get this info by looking into the php source code at

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c

```
switch (PS(session_status)) {
    case php_session_active:
        php_error(E_NOTICE, "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()");
        return;
        break;
```

if a session is allready started it will have no effect

Comment: I believe the code you've quoted refers to calling session_start one after another, without calling session_write_close in between.

Comment: I believe the PHP devs say "Not a bug" when the behavior is considered correct, not when the behavior doesn't exist.